# How to create an installer project for visual studio 2015 which will install into a directory of the same name as the main project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, installation

When running the installer created, the installer would say "Welcome to the [ProjectName]Setup Setup Wizard".  It should just be "Welcome to the [ProjectName] Setup Wizard".  It looks like the installer project is being installed, instead of the main project.  Not very professional. And I cannot change the installer project name to [ProjectName] because Visual Studio 2015 wont allow different projects to have the same name.  A picture is worth a thousand words, so here is the situation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of stating the obvious, it says that because the ProductName (in the setup project's properties window) is defined to be "CateringManagerSetup". So the easiest thing to do is delete that extra "Setup" from your product name.

It says "setup" in the Application Folder name probably because it's been added. The default location is [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName] so it appears again that a "setup" folder has been added to the Application Folder, as defined in the properties window of the Application Folder, or by adding a "Setup" folder to the Application Folder in the File System view in the project's IDE.

Property windows show when the item is selected and you click F4.